# Правильно ли реализована инкапсуляция в данном примере?

Tags: java, ооп

```
public class People {
    protected String name;
    protected int success;
    protected int respons;

    public String SayWhoAmI() {
        return "I am a human!";
    }
}

public class Students extends People {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public int getRespons() {
        return respons;
    }

    @Override
    public String SayWhoAmI() {
        return "I am a student now!";
    }

    Students(String name, int success, int respons) {
        this.name = name;
        this.success = success;
        this.respons = respons;
    }
}
```

Будет ли так правильнее?

```
private String name;
private int success;
private int respons;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public int getRespons() {
    return respons;
}
```

Comment: `People` -> `Person`, `Students` -> `Student`, `respons` -> `response`, `SayWhoAmI` -> `SayWhoIAm`

Comment: Не очень понял что это значит

Comment: Правильность относительна. Каких целей Вы хотели добиться этим кодом?

Comment: Код должен читаться, то есть быть, насколько возможно, близок к человеческой речи и не содержать грамматических ошибок.

Comment: нужны скрытые переменные name, success, respons, чтобы потом их использовать в массиве объектов.

Comment: Ну, кроме сокращенного respons от responsiblity, вроде ничего грамматически не правильным показаться не может. Или что-то еще?

Comment: Пожалуйста, помещайте код в вопрос, используя ссылку "править".

Comment: Егор Бугаенко сказал бы что в корне неверно :)

Answer (score 2):

Каша в коде.
Для правильной инкапсуляции нужно задать себе несколько вопросов:

1. Переменная необходима в базовом классе или ее можно перенести в наследника?
   В приведенных примерах все переменные могут быть перенесены в класс Students.
   Если же предполагаются другие классы от People, которые тоже будут использовать эти переменные, то они должны остаться в базовом классе.
2. Переменные базового класса *должны* быть видны в наследниках?
   В верхнем примере видны и могут быть изменены. Во втором примере нет. Правда, не понятно к какому классу они во втором примере относятся. 
   Открывать переменные для наследников можно в том случае, если это не может повлиять на поведение объекта в целом. Например, этого нельзя делать, если изменение переменной базового класса должно производиться через свойство с изменением состояния объекта (поменяли длину - изменился цвет).
3. Конструктор обычно принимает на вход те переменные, которые определены в классе, если их необходимо инициализировать.
   Следовательно, в первом примере для класса People должен быть определен конструктор. А наследник уже может его переопределить, если это будет необходимо.
4. Геттеры обычно определяются в том классе, где определены переменные. 
   Изменение состояния объекта в геттерах это вообще недопустимо (хорошо что этого в приведенных примерах нет)

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Если имя и два других поля есть у всех людей (студентов и не студентов), то и гетеры для них должны быть у всех, то есть принадлежать классу `People`.